# I deleted my system ui on my alcatel one touch fierce I need help

Tags: alcatel-one-touch-idol-s

I need help I accidentally unstalled my system ui on my alcatel one touch fierce and I need help on how I can get it back can I get it back?? I cant see my notification bar or my wallpaper and I can't screen shot someone please help me

Comment: ...how did you manage to do that?

Answer (score 0):

well you can install the OP from a computer or laptop... just look for JB 4.2.2 roms download it and pass it to an sdcard.. insert the sdcart to you phone.. next hold the power button and the up volume then a boot menu should come up.. press the recovery mode and just apply the update from the sdcard and there... if your still having trouble... check out tutorials on youtube... youre probably not gonna find a video on your exact phone... but just watch it so you can get an idea on how to do it